# Angular checkbox select all or select individual element from the table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have two scenarios here, one is user click an individual element and submits and other is user clicks select all button and submits so that, on the user's requirement, I want to fetch the item's details in the controller.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
        <div >
          <label class="btn btn-info">
            <input ng-model="vm.selectAll" type="checkbox"  name="selectAll" value="allitems" > Select all Items
          </label>
          <button ng-click="vm.purchaseItems(item)" class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" >Purchase selected Items</button>
       <table ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
          <tbody>
              <thead>
                <th ><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="vm.selectAll"/></th>
                <th >Student Id</th>
                <th >Name</th>
                <th >School</th>
             </thead>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td >{{item.studentId}}</td>
                <td >{{item.name}}</td>
                <td >{{item.schoolName}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
     </div>
```

**Controller**

```
 vm.purchaseItems = purchaseItems;

  function purchaseItems(item) {
  console.log(item); 
// I want to log only selected items either single or all based on user call
}
```

Should I  go with a directive or can it be done simply in the controller itself?

Comment: you need to filter items for checkbox model to true

Comment: use this demo of Github:https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Comment: @Abhishek a good one but has many bugs too

Comment: @VinodLouis a more descriptive answer would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: You should add a checkbox at the first columns of your data rows and your `ng-repeat` should be in `tr`. Try and update your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a variable to hold the selected value and then a filter function to return result see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/296/

```
this.setUnsetAll = function(selected){
 this.items.forEach(function(ele){
  ele.isSelected = selected;
 }); 
}

this.purchaseItems = function(){
var selectedItems = this.items.filter(function(ele){
return (ele.isSelected);
});

console.log(selectedItems)
}
```

Comment: to remove partial selection in case if any one i selected after all selection you need to remove select All as done here http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/297/